# regular expression to replace two (or more) consecutive characters by only one?

Tags: java, regex

In java, which regular expression can be used to replace these,
for example:

before:
aaabbb
after:
ab

before:
14442345 
after:
142345

thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In perl

```
s/(.)\1+/$1/g;
```

Does the trick, I assume if java has perl compatible regexps it should work too.

Edit: Here is what it means

```
s {
    (.)  # match any charater ( and capture it )
    \1   # if it is followed by itself 
    +    # One or more times
}{$1}gx;  # And replace the whole things by the first captured character (with g modifier to replace all occurences)
```

Edit: As others have pointed out, the syntax in Java would become

```
original.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");
```

remember to escape the \1

Comment: The java quantifiers are slightly different: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html . I guess original.replaceAll("(.){2,}", "$1"); should do the work (example worked for 2 and more but not if I wanted to replace three and more occurrences)

Answer (score 18):

```
String a = "aaabbb";
String b = a.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");
System.out.println("'" + a + "' -> '" + b + "'");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
"14442345".replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
originalString.replaceAll( "(.)\\1+", "$1" );
```

Answer (score 1):

**match pattern** (in Java/languages where \ must be escaped):

```
(.)\\1+
```

or (in languages where you can use strings which don't treat \ as escape character)

```
(.)\1+
```

**replacement**:

```
$1
```

Answer (score 0):

in TextEdit (assuming posix expressions)
find: [a]+[b]+
replace with: ab

Answer (score 0):

In Perl:

```
tr/a-z0-9//s;
```

Example:

```
$ perl -E'@a = (aaabbb, 14442345); for(@a) { tr/a-z0-9//s; say }'
ab
142345
```

If Java has no `tr` analog then:

```
s/(.)\1+/$1/sg; 
#NOTE: `s` modifier. It takes into account consecutive newlines.
```

Example:

```
$ perl -E'@a = (aaabbb, 14442345); for(@a) { s/(.)\1+/$1/sg; say }'
ab
142345
```

Answer (score 0):

Sugared with a Java 7 : Named Groups

```
static String cleanDuplicates(@NonNull final String val) { 
      assert val != null;
      return val.replaceAll("(?<dup>.)\\k<dup>+","${dup}");
}
```