# How to find two adjacent repeating digits and replace them with a single digit in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to find two adjacent repeating digits in a string and replace with a single one. How to do this in Java. Some examples:

123345 should be 12345
 77433211 should be 74321

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106067/regular-expression-to-replace-two-or-more-consecutive-characters-by-only-one Related general case

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Probably a `replaceAll("(\\d)\\1+", "$1")`

- `$` plays a special role in a replacing string, designating the first capturing group.
- `+` allows for replacing as many identical number as possible `(\\d)\\1` would only replace them by pair: `777xx` => `77xx` (thank you [Ben Doom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12267/ben-doom) for the remark)

So:

```
System.out.println("77433211".replaceAll("(\\d)\\1+", "$1"));
```

will return

```
74321
```

---

```
String java.lang.String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
```

Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

An invocation of this method of the form `str.replaceAll(regex, repl)` yields exactly the same result as the expression

```
java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).replaceAll(repl)
```

---

**Warning**: `String.replaceAll()` function does not modify the String on which it is applied. It returns a modified String (or *a new String with the same content* if the pattern does not match anything)

So you need to affect the result of a `replaceAll()` call to itself to actually update your String with the regexp changes.

```
String aString = "77433211"
aString = aString.replaceAll("(\\d)\\1+", "$1"));
```

Comment: It should be noted that this *only* works in pairs, so 777 becomes 77 ((77)7) and 7777 becomes 77 ((77)(77)).  To replace all repeats, use /(\\d)\\1+/

Answer (score 5):

I finally did it myself. Those who are looking for the solution, this is how I did it:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class RepetingDigits{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word = "77433211";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d)\\1");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
        word = matcher.replaceAll("$1");  
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

Even simpler:

```
**word = word.replaceAll("(\\d)\\1", "$1");**
```

Comment: Yes, but again, a simple "77433211".replaceAll("(\\d)\\1", "$1"); is enough ;)

Comment: Yes that did too, I just forgot to assign the return value and thought that it doesn't work. Thanks VonC for your help. A couple of votes to you for that :-)

Answer (score 0):

using a regex:

```
var myString='123345'
myString.replace(/([0-9])\1/g,'$1')
```

that will match exactly 2 repeats.

```
'123334'.replace(/([0-9])\1+/g,'$1')
```

Comment: That's not Java... but the idea is sound.

Comment: You could use this regexp in combination with java.util.regex.Pattern en java.util.regex.Matcher classes.

Comment: There's a replaceAll() convenience method in the String class, so you don't have to use Pattern or Matcher, but you have to write the regex in the form of a String literal, as VonC demonstrated, because Java doesn't have regex literals.

Answer (score 0):

This is a regular expression mathing two repeating digits (x being the digit)

```
[x]{2}(?!=[x])
```