# Remove doubled letter from a string using java

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to remove a doubled letter from a string using regex operations in java.
Eg: PRINCEE -> PRINCE
    APPLE -> APLE

Comment: Homework? Why do you need to use a regex?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find two adjacent repeating digits and replace them with a single digit in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264530/how-to-find-two-adjacent-repeating-digits-and-replace-them-with-a-single-digit-in)

Answer (score 13):

### Simple Solution (remove duplicate characters)

Like this:

```
final String str = "APPLEE";
String replaced = str.replaceAll("(.)\\1", "$1");
System.out.println(replaced);
```

Output:

> APLE

### Not just any Chracters, Letters only

As @Jim comments correctly, the above matches any double character, not just letters. Here are a few variations that just match letters:

```
// the basics, ASCII letters. these two are equivalent:
str.replaceAll("([A-Za-z])\\1", "$1");
str.replaceAll("(\\p{Alpha})\\1", "$1");

// Unicode Letters
str.replaceAll("(\\p{L})\\1", "$1");

// anything where Character.isLetter(ch) returns true
str.replaceAll("(\\p{javaLetter})\\1", "$1");
```

### References:

For additional reference:

1. [`Character.isLetter(ch)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) (javadocs)
2. any method in [`Character`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) of
   the form `Character.isXyz(char)`
   enables a pattern named
   `\p{javaXyz}` (mind the
   capitalization). This mechanism is
   [described in the Pattern
   javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#jcc)
3. Unicode blocks and categories can
   also be matched with the `\p` and
   `\P` constructs as in Perl. `\p{prop}`
   matches if the input has the
   property prop, while `\P{prop}` does
   not match if the input has that
   property. This mechanism is [also
   described in the Pattern
   javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#ubc)

Comment: This will also remove doubled non letters, such as whitespace.

Comment: @Jim yes, obviously. But since the input strings seem to be letters only, it doesn't make a difference in this case

Comment: it doesn't work in case if String is like "cdcdcdcd"?

Comment: @eatSleepCode no that's a different use case. the task here was to remove two consecutive identical characters. what's your use case?

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd how the regex can be formed for string like "ccdcddcdcdcdc"?

Comment: @eatSleepCode I don't get it, that should work with the example above, shouldn't it?

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd no it isn't working, It doesn't produce output as "cd", since those are the only unique characters over there.

Comment: @eatSleepCode ok I get what you mean. that's not the topic of this question, which is about removing duplicate consecutive characters. What you want can most easily be done by storing characters in a set ( like this: http://ideone.com/nX3FuX ). You can't reasonably do this with regex.

Answer (score 6):

```
String s = "...";
String replaced = s.replaceAll( "([A-Z])\\1", "$1" );
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to replace just duplicate ("AA"->"A", "AAA" -> "AA") use

```
public String undup(String str) {
  return str.replaceAll("(\\w)\\1", "$1");
}
```

To replace triplicates etc use:  `str.replaceAll("(\\w)\\1+", "$1");`

To replace only a single dupe is a long string (AAAA->AAA, AAA->AA) use:  `str.replaceAll("(\\w)(\\1+)", "$2");`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done simply by iterating over the String instead of having to resort to regexes.

```
StringBuilder ret=new StringBuilder(text.length());

if (text.length()==0) return "";
ret.append(text.charAt(0));
for(int i=1;i<text.length();i++){
  if (text.charAt(i)!=text.charAt(i-1))
    ret.append(text.charAt(i));
}

return ret.toString();
```

Comment: `if (text.charAt(i)!=text.charAt(i-1))` this will throw an Exception in the first loop execution, `text.charAt(-1)` fails

Comment: @Sean Patrick Flyod True. `if (text.length()==0) return "";` could be changed to `if (text.length() < 2) return text;` to avoid this.

Comment: @jensgram nope, that wouldn't help, it would have to be something like this: `if (i==0 || text.charAt(i)!=text.charAt(i-1))`

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd Oops, you're right. The `int i=0` should be `int i=1`, too. (It is entirely possible that I've missed other aspects.)

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd: Thanks. I have corrected the code. I should know better than to post untested code here.

Comment: @MAK the current version is not too elegant with the extra charAt() call, but it will certainly work and that's worth a +1