# Creating a for loop to detect if there are 2 of the same characters next to eachother

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to figure out how to make a `for loop` that will detect if there are 2 of the same letters `g` in this case next to each-other, there will be more than one instance of "g" in the string.

Here's what I have,

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String a;
a = keyboard.next();


if (a.charAt(a.indexOf(g) + 1 ) == "g"){
    for ( ??  ; ??   ; ??  ){
    System.out.println("True");
    System.out.println("False");
    }
}
else System.out.println("False");`
```

I am not sure of some of the values or concepts I am meant to be using, I am only familiar with most of the basics.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  String a;
  a = keyboard.next();

  char[] chararray = a.toCharArray();
  char  temp = '\0';
  boolean repeat = false;

  for (char s : chararray) {
      if(s==temp)
      {
          System.out.println("repeat");
          repeat = true;
          break;
      }
      temp = s;
  }
  System.out.println(repeat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, without any loop at all:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String a;
a = keyboard.next();
if (a.indexOf("gg") != -1) 
    System.out.println("True");
else
    System.out.println("False");
keyboard.close();
```

I've used `indexOf` cause if you wanted be able to do something with the position of the occurrence.

And if you're not interested in the position of "gg" in your string (if it occurs) you can just replace `a.indexOf("gg") != -1` with `a.contains("gg")` as Vikiiii said.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression to find if there are two of the same characters next to each other.

Just check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4725079/2182503