# How to replace double/more letters to a single letter?

Tags: php, regex

I need to convert any letter that occur twice or more within a word with a single letter of itself.

For example:

```
School -> Schol
Google -> Gogle
Gooooogle -> Gogle
VooDoo -> Vodo
```

I tried the following, but stuck at the second parameter in eregi_replace.

```
$word = 'Goooogle';
$word2 = eregi_replace("([a-z]{2,})", "?", $word);
```

If I use `\\\1` to replace ?, it would display the exact match. 
How do I make it single letter?

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [regular expression to replace two (or more) consecutive characters by only one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106067/regular-expression-to-replace-two-or-more-consecutive-characters-by-only-one)

By the way: you should use the `preg_*` (PCRE) functions instead of the deprecated `ereg_*` functions (POSIX).

[Richard Szalay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801545/how-to-replace-double-more-letters-to-a-single-letter/801554#801554)'s answer leads the right way:

```
$word = 'Goooogle';
$word2 = preg_replace('/(\w)\1+/', '$1', $word);
```

Comment: Dude, that is awesome. I guess I have to switch over to PCRE! Thanks!

Comment: `\w` matches more than just letters. It matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Answer (score 3):

Not only are you capturing the entire thing (instead of just the first character), but `{2,}` rematching [a-z] (not the original match). It should work if you use:

```
$word2 = eregi_replace("(\w)\1+", "\\1", $word);
```

Which backreferences the original match. You can replace \w with [a-z] if you wish.

The + is required for your Goooogle example (for the JS regex engine, anyway), but I'm not sure why.

Remember that you will need to use the "global" flag ("g").

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$string = "thhhhiiiissssss hasss sooo mannnny letterss";
$string = preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z])\1+/', '$1', $string);
```

How this works:

```
/ ... /    # Marks the start and end of the expression.
([a-zA-Z]) # Match any single a-z character lowercase or uppercase.
\1+        # One or more occurrence of the single character we matched previously.

$1         
\1+        # The same single character we matched previously.
```