# preg_replace pattern needed. replace double chars with single char

Tags: php, regex

I'm not that familiar with patterns so that's why I'm asking it here instead of going through a trail and error proces. I know it is not the best way to learn but I have more important things to code.

basically I want to replace any double occurrences of a given char with a single char. This is for cleaning input strings before validation. for example

```
$string='hello///stack/overflow/ //  //!';
$string2='hello((stack(overflow(((( (!';
$clean= preg_replace($pattern, '/',$string );
$clean2= preg_replace($pattern, '(',$string2 );
echo $clean;
echo $clean2;
```

the above code should echo *hello/stack/overflow/!* and *hello(stack(overflow(!*, with the correct pattern of course... :-)

any help appreciated!

peace

edit: actually I would be more then happy with a pattern that does the job without dealing with the whitespaces. I can strip them like so

```
preg_replace('/\s+/xms', '', trim($value))
```

and then deal with the double chars...

Comment: and I'll get my master PHP diploma if I do it? Homework?

Comment: `replace any double occurrences of a given char with a single char` doesn't match with your example: output from first string will be as follows: `hello/stack/overflow/ / /!`

Comment: well I would be happy to have a pattern that does it without dealing with the spaces. I can strip whitespace out with an other pattern...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace double/more letters to a single letter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801545/how-to-replace-double-more-letters-to-a-single-letter)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to replace only double occurences? From your example seems you want to replace 2 or more same characters.

If you need to do it only for some specific chars use

```
$value = preg_replace('/\\{2,}/', '\', trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $value));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your regex pattern is incorrect to start with, the use of the / is designed to identify the start and end of a pattern. For example `$pattern='/-/';` will look for the - to replace

The full example of a regex would be as follows:

```
$string='this/is/my/pattern';
$pattern='///';
$replacement=' ';
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

To answer your question, nobody could explain it as well as in [this article](http://randomdrake.com/2008/04/10/php-and-regex-replacing-repeating-characters-with-single-characters-in-a-string/) so check that out.

The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) on preg_replace is good so I would recommend going through that also.

Comment: Except that that program has errors: it is simply wrong to write `[A-z]`.

Comment: Your absolutely right, I read the article and have created my own application out of it - I didn't copy and paste the application written. For anyone who doesn't already know the correct way for upper and lower case alpha is [A-Za-z], you can also use [A-Z] or [a-z]. Also, @tchrist is referring to the article not the PHP documentation if you're wondering. Thanks for the comment mate

Comment: Actually, the pattern for cased letters is `[\p{Lu}\p{Ll}\p{Lt}]` or all letters `\pL`.  Technically, there are also some modifier letters that have lowercase although they don’t change case when uppercased. PHP does not support the standard Unicode properties `\p{Cased_Letter}` vs `\p{Cased}` for any cased code point.