# Replace many occurance of alphabets by one in preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I was wondering can we replace many occurances of any alphabet in a word with only one occurance of the same alphabet only using preg_replace in PHP.

for example: 
it should replace *looooovveee* by *love*.

If it is not possible to do that using preg_replace then tell me the methods of doing it in PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes it is possible with `preg_replace()`.

Comment: @beingkvn I won't write the code for you. Show your code and I will help you to get it working.

Comment: @beingkvn The only difference from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/801571/3110638) is, that you want to use `[A-Za-z]` instead of `\w` which is a [short](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for word character and contains `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.